# Getting error in Huawei account kit signin for agc failed code 203817988

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I am implementing an app for which i want user to sign in using Huawei account. I have integrated the Huawei account kit.
But  I get following exception when i am trying to sign  in using Huawei account.

“signin for agc failed: code : 203817988 message: third provider is disabled”

Pelase help me resolving this issue

Answer (score 3):

1. You have to enable Auth service in App Gallery connect
2. Log in to AppGallery Connect and select My apps.
3. Select your Application
   4 . Click Develop - > Manage API  enable auth service
   [image]
4. Click  Build from left panel , select auth service
5. Enable Huawei account. Provide necessary details.
   [image]

7 . Download agc-connect.json and integrate into yopur application by pasting it in app folder